# Gameloft Game Graphics problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, graphics

I installed a Gameloft game Brother in Arms. But the graphics of the game is shown as below.

Use 2.3.3 on Samsung S2

Any idea why its not being displayed ?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. Our team will look into this :) If you have additional details, please send an e-mail at support@gameloft.com. Have a great day!:)

Comment: Also have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and had the exact same problem with HAWKS ,I installed a different version and it worked fine.I guess it's because of the mali gpu and compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung elected not to include all the *texture compression* formats when they integrated the Mali-400 GPU into the Exynos chip that powers the Galaxy S II. This is because some formats are patented and would require Samsung to pay a fee to the patent-holder to support them.

Because the S II was the first high-end phone not to support these formats, most game vendors weren't ready to use alternative texture compression formats in their games, and such games will draw with missing textures, like in your screenshot. Also, at the time the S II came out, Google Play made it very hard to support multiple texture formats with one app: you had to include all the formats in one APK file, making it unnecessarily large.

It's now much easier to build for different compression formats and automatically select the right textures for the device you're running on.